# System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException: An operations error occurred.

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory

I'm trying to get the email address from a user that is submitting an ASP.NET form on the local intranet. When testing this on my local machine it works fine. But when I publish and begin testing it in production it doesn't like line 74.

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

An operations error occurred.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException: An operations error occurred.


Source Error: 


Line 71:         adSearcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
Line 72:         adSearcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(samaccountname=" + userInQuestion + "))";
Line 73:         SearchResult userObject = adSearcher.FindOne();
Line 74:         if (userObject != null) 
Line 75:         { 

Source File: c:\Web\Support-t\Content\Default.aspx.cs    Line: 73 

Stack Trace: 


[DirectoryServicesCOMException (0x80072020): An operations error occurred.
]
   System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail) +628309
   System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind() +44
   System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_AdsObject() +42
   System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher.FindAll(Boolean findMoreThanOne) +98
   System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher.FindOne() +44
   _Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Web\Support-t\Content\Default.aspx.cs:73
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +71
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3178



--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.18033
```

This block of code is in my page load just for testing purposes so in can get an immediate result....but it never get to the loading of the page in production but works fine when debugging in VS on local machine...

```
IIdentity id = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
        WindowsIdentity winId = id as WindowsIdentity;

        if (id == null) 
        {
            txtDetailedProblem.Text = "Identity is not a windows identity";
            return;
        }

        string userInQuestion = winId.Name.Split('\\')[1];
        string myDomain = winId.Name.Split('\\')[0]; // this is the domain that the user is in
        // the account that this program runs in should be authenticated in there                    
        DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + myDomain);
        DirectorySearcher adSearcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry);

        adSearcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
        adSearcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(samaccountname=" + userInQuestion + "))";
        SearchResult userObject = adSearcher.FindOne();
        if (userObject != null) 
        {
            string[] props = new string[] {"mail"};
            foreach (string prop in props) 
            {
                txtTEST.Text = prop.ToString() + " " + userObject.Properties[prop][0].ToString();
            }
        }
```

Comment: I assume you have permission to access the AD where the identity on your production webserver is not. Which identity is configured in the apppool of your production webserver?

Comment: possible duplicate of [System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException: An operations error occurred](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13688031/system-directoryservices-directoryservicescomexception-an-operations-error-occu)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
IIdentity id = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
            WindowsIdentity winId = id as WindowsIdentity;

            if (id == null)
            {
                CurrentUserEmail = "identity is not a windows identity";
                return;
            }

            var name = winId.Name;

            string userInQuestion = name.Split('\\')[1];
            string myDomain = name.Split('\\')[0]; // this is the domain that the user is in
            // the account that this program runs in should be authenticated in there                    

            using (HostingEnvironment.Impersonate())
            {
                DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + myDomain);
                DirectorySearcher adSearcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry);

                adSearcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
                adSearcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(samaccountname=" + userInQuestion + "))";
                SearchResult userObject = adSearcher.FindOne();
                if (userObject != null)
                {
                    string[] props = new string[] {"mail"};
                    foreach (string prop in props)
                    {   //when it works set variable to CurrentUserEmail instead of txtDetailPrblem textbox
                        CurrentUserEmail = userObject.Properties[prop][0].ToString();
                    }
                }

            }
```