# ASP.NET BOILERPLATE - Ldap AUTHENTICATION Issue

Tags: ldap, zero, aspnetboilerplate

I'm using version 3.1.1.
I've enabled LDAP in the CoreModule.cs as follows:

1- Downloaded Abp.Zero.Ldap

2- I extened LdapAuthenticationSource as shown below:

```
public class MyLdapAuthenticationSource : LdapAuthenticationSource<Tenant, User>

{

public MyLdapAuthenticationSource(ILdapSettings settings, IAbpZeroLdapModuleConfig ldapModuleConfig)
        : base(settings, ldapModuleConfig)

{

}

}
```

3- Set module dependency as shown below:

[DependsOn(typeof(AbpZeroLdapModule))]

```
public class MyApplicationCoreModule : AbpModule

{

public override void PreInitialize()

{

Configuration.Modules.ZeroLdap().Enable(typeof (MyLdapAuthenticationSource));

}

}
```

4- Lastly I set 'Abp.Zero.Ldap.IsEnabled' setting as  true.

While working on my own pc I can login with active directory username and password. But when I publish it to the server I get the error as shown below:

"An internal error occourred during your request"

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWRJ5.png)

I'm waiting your support.

Best regards..

Comment: what does the log say?

Comment: `System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException (0x80072020): An

Comment: write the full exception log

Comment: maybe an answer here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13688031/system-directoryservices-directoryservicescomexception-an-operations-error-occu