# ASP.NET Boilerplate: Active Directory Ldap Authentication Invalid Username or Password

Tags: active-directory, ldap, aspnetboilerplate

I've setup a test solution to experiment with Ldap Authentication.

I've followed the [documentation](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Zero/User-Management#ldap-active-directory) and looked into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51150845/asp-net-boilerplate-ldap-authentication-issue) as well, then I've setup my `MyLdapAuthenticationSource` in the Core project along with the package `Abp.Zero.Ldap` and set `Configuration.Modules.ZeroLdap().UseUserPrincipalNameAsUserName = true;`

**When I tried to login I receive Invalid Username or Password message.**

Additionally, I setup a default .NET 5 Microsoft solution to verify that I'm able to connect to the Active Directory directly and it worked as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this by changing the `Settings` in the application and DB, it was mentioned in the documentation by wasn't detailed on how to change them.

First:

I've defined a new Setting to be added to the DB in `DefaultSettingsCreator` in the Seed Host folders under `EntityFrameworkCore` project:

`AddSettingIfNotExists(LdapSettingNames.IsEnabled, "true", tenantId);`

Second:

I've defined a new `SettingDefinition` in the `AppSettingProvider` in the Configuration folder under `Core` project:

`new SettingDefinition(LdapSettingNames.IsEnabled, "true", scopes: SettingScopes.Application | SettingScopes.Tenant | SettingScopes.User)`

Hope this helps future users.