# UserPrincipal Object, Active Directory Query: DirectoryServicesCOMException

Tags: c#, asp.net

Apologies for duplicate of [System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException: An operations error occurred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13688031/system-directoryservices-directoryservicescomexception-an-operations-error-occu?answertab=active#tab-top) but I can't comment yet and there's no answer.

The solution from this question, did not work. [Error on publishing: System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9181435/error-on-publishing-system-directoryservices-directoryservicescomexception)

I've got a new ASP.NET MVC 3 web application project with Razor view engine in Visual Studio 2010. It is as generated with the addition of two lines of code added to the home controller and the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` reference added to the project.

This runs just fine on my local PC, but I get an error on a Windows 2008 R2 IIS 7.5 site I've created.

The site uses the `defaultAppPool`, which is using `ApplicationPoolIdentity`. The root site folder has been granted `IUSR` and `IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool` read permissions.

The two lines of code in the controller are:

```
PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
ViewBag.name = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, User.Identity.Name).DisplayName;
```

The error I get is:

> *System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException: An operations error occurred.*

Stack Trace:

> [DirectoryServicesCOMException (0x80072020): An operations error occurred.]
>   System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail) +781
>   System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind() +44
>   System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_AdsObject() +42
>   System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection.PopulateList() +29
>   System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection..ctor(DirectoryEntry entry, String propertyName) +119
>   System.DirectoryServices.PropertyCollection.get_Item(String propertyName) +163
>       System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.DoLDAPDirectoryInitNoContainer()
>   +535649
>   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.DoDomainInit() +51
>   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.Initialize() +141
>   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.get_QueryCtx() +42
>       System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal.FindByIdentityWithTypeHelper(PrincipalContext context, Type principalType, Nullable`1 identityType, String identityValue, DateTime refDate) +27
>
>       System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(PrincipalContext
>   context, String identityValue) +95
>
>   ActiveDirectory.Controllers.HomeController.Index() in C:\projects\ActiveDirectory\ActiveDirectory\Controllers\HomeController.cs:18
>
>   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +79
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +248
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
>   parameters) +39
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass15.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__12() +125
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter
>   filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +640
>       System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor,
>   IDictionary`2 parameters) +312
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, String actionName) +691
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +162
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +305
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb.b__5() +62
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0() +20
>       System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +469
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +375

Be nice, it's my first question!

Comment: Did you get an `.InnerException` (possible multiple levels deep) - those messages could be really helpful ...

Comment: No. that's the full stack trace, unfortunately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely this is a permissions issue. Check that the account the App Pool is running under has the authority to perform these Active Directory calls. If it's a local machine account, it probably won't.

You can find more information here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms180891(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Thanks Pete. The link you provided led me to identify the double hop issue here.  I can either use impersonation with a specified domain account or changing the ApplicationPool identity from ApplicationPoolIdentity to NetworkService gets me up and running with the code querying the active directory.

Comment: To find out who IIS is running under you can use: `string currentUser = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;`